# Return an Index number from a collection VBA

Tags: excel, collections, indexing, key, vba

If I have created a collection, can I search search the collection and **RETURN THE INDEX** number from within the collection?

Due to my newbie status, I can't post screenshots of what I'm trying to do, so let me try to explain what I'm trying to accomplish:

I have a history log from a warehouse database in Excel format that is several thousand lines long-- each line representing a transaction of product moving in or out of as many as 10 different bins.  My goal is to identify all the possible different bins in the thousands of lines, copy/transpose those ~10 bins to column headers, and then go through each transaction and copy the transaction quantity (+1,-3, etc) to the correct column, thus being able separate the transactions and more easily identify and generate an accounting of when product moved in/out of each respective bin.  This would *sort of* look like a PivotTable, but that isn't really how it would work.

Here is the code I am working on so far, with comments.  My problem is explained in the last comment:

```
Sub ForensicInventory()
Dim BINLOCAT As Collection
Dim Rng As Range
Dim Cell As Range
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim vNum As Variant
Dim BINcol As Integer
Dim ACTcol As Integer
Dim QTYcol As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim x As Long

'This part is used to find the relevant columns that will be used later
BINcol = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Find(What:="BINLABEL", LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Column
ACTcol = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Find(What:="ACTION", LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Column
QTYcol = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Find(What:="QUANTITY", LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Column

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

i = 0
Set sh = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Set Rng = sh.Range(sh.Cells(2, BINcol), sh.Cells(Rows.Count, BINcol).End(xlUp))
Set BINLOCAT = New Collection

'This next section searches the bin column and builds the collection of unique bins that I am interested in.
On Error Resume Next
    For Each Cell In Rng.Cells
        If Len(Cell.Value) <> 8 And Not IsEmpty(Cell) Then
            BINLOCAT.Add Cell.Value, CStr(Cell.Value)
        End If
    Next Cell
On Error GoTo 0

'Now I take those unique bin names and I put them into a column header on the same spreadsheet, starting in column 10, and spacing every 2 cells thereafter.
For Each vNum In BINLOCAT
    Cells(1, 10 + i).Value = vNum
    i = i + 2
Next vNum

    'Here is where the problem exists for me.  This code works and succeeds in copying the QTY
    'to column 10, but what I really want to do is determine the index number of the bin from BINLOCAT,
    'and use that index number to place the value under the appropriate column header.
For x = 2 To lastrow
  Select Case Cells(x, ACTcol).Value
      Case "MOVE-IN"
        Cells(x, 10).Value = Cells(x, QTYcol).Value
      Case "MOVE-OUT"
        Cells(x, 10).Value = -Cells(x, QTYcol).Value
      Case Else
  End Select
Next x

End Sub
```

In the "For x = 2 to lastrow" loop, I need to find a way to get the INDEX number (1, 2, 3, etc.) from searching for the bin in collection BINLOCAT.  BINLOCAT, once created, is static.  I envision something like:

```
neededcolumn = BINLOCAT.item(cells(x,BINcol).value).index (pseudocode)
```

Then I would replace the 10s in the Case Stmt with "neededcolumn" and this would work.

Maybe I am taking the wrong approach, but it seems to me like I need the collection to be able to do the search portion efficiently.  Any thoughts or links to a solution?  Based on what I've read, elsewhere, I think that this ability as I'm describing it is not available, but I'm not sure I've understood everything I've read about collections thus far.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Disclaimer: Okay, I am going to answer my own question, but I was led to this answer based on @Rory's comment at 13:07 on 8/18.  So, thank you, Rory!  Rory's answer proper did not enlighten me in the way I needed (or I'm too dumb to see it -- always possible), so I'm not accepting his answer but I want to acknowledge his help.  I still suspect there might be a better way than what I am doing, so please feel free to comment/answer/correct me.

In the interest of simplicity and thoroughness, assume the following starting data:
Range("A1:A16")=

- BM182B
- BM182B
- BM182B
- BM182B
- BM182B
- AS662B
- BM182B
- BM182B
- BM182B
- BM182B
- AS702B
- AS642B
- BM182B
- BM182B
- BM182B
- BM182B

Based on Rory's comment, this is the first piece of code I came up with:

```
    Sub TestofCollection()
    Dim BinCollection1 As Collection
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim x As Integer

    Set BinCollection1 = New Collection

    n = 1

    On Error Resume Next
        For Each Cell In Range("A1:A16")
            BinCollection1.Add n, CStr(Cell.Value)
            n = n + 1
        Next Cell
    On Error GoTo 0

    For x = 1 To BinCollection1.Count
        Range("B" & x).Value = BinCollection1.Item(x)
    Next x

    End Sub
```

The problem with this is that output, or the "index" I get, is actually the positional location of each bin during its first occurrence in the list.  So the result in the output segment is "1,6,11,12" rather than the desired "1,2,3,4" for the list "BM182B, AS662B, AS702B, AS642B".  Whether there is a better way, I do not know, but my solution was to create a "collection of a collection" as follows in the next code:

```
    Sub TestofCollection2()
    Dim BinCollection1 As Collection
    Dim BinCollection2 As Collection

    Set BinCollection1 = New Collection
    Set BinCollection2 = New Collection

    n = 1

    On Error Resume Next
        For Each Cell In Range("A1:A16")
            BinCollection1.Add Cell.Value, CStr(Cell.Value)
        Next Cell

        For Each x In BinCollection1
            BinCollection2.Add n, BinCollection1.Item(x)
            n = n + 1
        Next x
    On Error GoTo 0

    For x = 1 To BinCollection2.Count
        Range("C" & x).Value = BinCollection2.Item(x)
    Next x

    'Test output result should be 3 below
    MsgBox "Test Output:  " & BinCollection2.Item("as702b")

    End Sub
```

So now, based on this double-collection effort, I can search my multi-thousand line columns of bins and determine their index to create my offset.  The index shows up as "1,2,3,4" using those keys in the list.

This is my first question and first answer on Stack Overflow.  I will probably give this a couple days to see if anyone has a better answer, but then I will "accept" my own answer here since this is what helped me (can I "unaccept" my answer if a better one shows up later?).  Again, comments or suggestions greatly appreciated and accepted.  Thank you for viewing.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a for each loop, use a `for n = 1 to BINLOCAT.Count` loop - then n is your index. Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: I had not thought of that approach to getting an index, but where exactly are you suggesting I would use that?  The code works as I intended/hoped in the two "For Each" loops.  My problem exists below those loops in the For x = 2 to lastrow, which is the loop I am using to cycle through each line of several thousand lines of warehouse history log.  If I did what I think you are suggesting, I would have to put something akin to the following inside that loop: For N = 1 to BINLOCAT.count; If Cell.value = BINLOCAT.item(n) then index = N; Endif; Next N.  That might work, but cumbersome.

Comment: You'd put the `For x = 2 To lastrow` loop inside the `For Each vNum In BINLOCAT` loop, where you are writing out headers. It would be better to just store the index number rather than the cell value in the collection though!

Comment: Ooh!  I think I know what to do now!  I'll get back to you, but thanks!  I think I have the solution based on that last comment.

Comment: I did get this to work based on your suggestion in the comment above, but I needed to do it with two collections (1st one gets the unique bins to be used as keys from the thousands of lines in the log; 2nd collection is created using the 1st collection with index as the value and unique bins as keys).  I will clean it up and post what I did later.  I don't think what I did was very "clean" or that I have a great grasp on the situation.  But it works!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  I have posted what I hope is a clear and as concise an answer to my question after thinking on your comments and getting my problem solved.  I have tried to acknowledge you appropriately.  Cheers!